# Wordpress can't find database hosted in Docker

Tags: wordpress, docker

I've currently got a setup where I'm hosting my wordpress site locally using nginx, and I have my database running inside a docker container. My goal is to host a lot of sites on this machine, and for sanity, I don't want to have to spin up a 50 docker containers, but instead just rely on my local nginx.

Below is my docker-compose for my database. I'm exposing the database at port 3306, and I tell wordpress to use `localhost:3306`, but I always get the error: `Error establishing a database connection`.

I've also tried sharing the volume of `/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock` and using `localhost:<absolute path>/mysqld/mysqld.sock`, which resulted in the same problem.

I setup phpmyadmin to verify that I can connect to the database, and everything looks good there.

I'm out of ideas and have been stuck for hours. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
version: '3.1'
services:

  wordpress-db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
      MYSQL_USER: wordpress_user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: example
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: example
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    volumes:
      - ./db:/var/lib/mysql
      # - ./mysqld/mysqld.sock:/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
    networks:
      - back

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: wordpress-db
    ports:
      - 2080:80
    links:
      - wordpress-db
    volumes:  
      - /sessions
    depends_on:
      - wordpress-db
    networks:
      - back

networks:
  back:
```

Comment: I think you need to allow the connection in your DB settings something like 0.0.0.0 in your DB settings

Comment: How does your wp-config.php look like?

Comment: @LinPy Good thought. I just tried that, but now what address do I use to connect to it?

Comment: @mynd I'm still in the initial setup where wordpress is asking me my Database name, username, password, database host etc. Basically it's using this information to generate the wp-config.php.

Comment: localhost also since the wordpress runs on the host not the container

Comment: @LinPy I tried swapping out the mysql.cnf file as suggested here to set the setting you suggested. It didn't work.

Comment: do you have anything in the DB logs ?

Comment: Nope. :( I do not.

Comment: run `telnet localhost 3306`from your HOST

Comment: @spierce7 your wordpress is also some docker container ? Or, it's running from host machine ?

Comment: Running on my host machine.